# Zend Framework 1 - remote database connection via ssh tunnel

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to connect to my customer remote database.

I'm able to establish ssh tunnel with command:

```
ssh -vvv -i path_to_private_key -L 3308:127.0.0.1:3307 ssh_user@ssh_host
```

and connect to his database with:

```
mysql -u database_user -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3308
```

But when I want to configure my zend framework project to read data from this database, nothing happen (even there is no logs in apache2 error logs)

Below my configurations from application.ini file:

```
resources.db.adapter = "mysqli"
resources.db.params.host = 127.0.0.1
resources.db.params.port = 3308

resources.db.params.dbname = database_name
resources.db.params.username = database_user
resources.db.params.password = database_password
resources.db.params.profiler = false
```

I have no idea what could be wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a slight change to your ssh command.

```
ssh -N -L -i path_to_private_key 3307:mysqlhost:3306 ssh-user@ssh-host
```

Where 3307 is your local port and mysqlhost is the mysql host you're connecting to, not localhost. Now, your config should look like:

```
resources.db.adapter = "mysqli"
resources.db.params.host = 127.0.0.1
resources.db.params.port = 3307

resources.db.params.dbname = database_name
resources.db.params.username = database_user
resources.db.params.password = database_password
```

For reference from the manual:

```
-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports (pro-
         tocol version 2 only).
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately this is not solution for my problem. Last days turned out that it was problem on my customer side, with my command everything was fine. But of course thank for interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not solution for my problem. Last days turned out that it was problem on my customer side, with my command everything was fine.